# Mutually immiscible liquids

Tags: immiscibility

How many mutually immiscible liquids can be stored in a glass bottle at S.T.P.?

According to

> PATTLE, R. E. (1950). Systems of Mutually Immiscible Liquid Layers. Nature, 165(4188), 203–204.

a system of 6 immiscible phases can be formed (including mercury), but the ammonia layer disappears after a month. They suggest gallium could add another layer, giving:

1. ammonia solution
2. isobutyl alcohol
3. liquid paraffin
4. potassium carbonate solution
5. methylene iodide
6. gallium
7. mercury

Could silicone oil and fluorocarbons create additional stable layers, and have there been any other systems suggested since 1950? I saw a 2006 [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiphasic_liquid#cite_note-1) with allegedly 8 phases.

Comment: I guess they could. Temporarily there cold be much more layers even from miscible stuff.

Comment: Better than gallium, could the alloy Galistan be used? It’s a mixture of Gallium, indium and tin. Other liquids like Bromine, Cesium and NaK might have some potential but may just react explosively.

Answer (score 2):

If one allows *miscible* liquids, there could be layers with just two solvents, with differing amounts of solutes added to make one layer denser than another. The layers might stay separated for months or years, [unless shaken or stirred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaken,_not_stirred).

By adding denser solutes, and by increasing the amount dissolved, the series could be extended indefinitely, with alternating miscible layers separated by a non-miscible layer.

For starters, a thought experiment:

- Top layer octanes, 0.7 g/ml
- Ammonia water, 0.9 g/ml
- Octanes + a little bromoethane, 0.95 g/ml
- Water, 1.0 g/ml
- Octanes + more bromoethane, 1.1 g/ml
- Water + $\ce{MgSO4}$, 1.2 g/ml
- Octanes + yet more bromoethane, 1.3 g/ml
- Water + $\ce{BiCl3 + HCl}$, 1.4 g/ml
- usw.

Actual calculations are left to experimenter ;-)

And as for shaking and stirring, it would be interesting to see everything merge into just two layers.