Search for liquid (Density atleast 1.01g/cm^3)
For an experiment, I need an liquid which is only slightly denser than water but is not a liquid mixed with water.
Essentially I need to layer 3 liquids, one of which is water (density: 1.0g/cm^3), one more liquid which has a density of 1.1g/cm^3 - so I am searching for a third liquid with a density between these values. (This liquid I am searching for would, if all three liquids were put into a container, be in the middle, with water being on top of it, due to density)
The liquid I am searching for is not allowed to be capable of mixing with water and is thereby likewise not allowed to be mixed with salts. (so brines)
I've been searching and searching - one idea was to use silicone oil, but could not find any which fits the threshhold..
I am grateful for ever answer.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/121642/mutually-immiscible-liquids https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/641/liquid-which-neither-dissolves-in-water-nor-oil https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141025/i-need-help-finding-several-immiscible-liquids

I would advice some fine density tuning by mixing two miscible nonpolar solvents with density lower and higher than water. // What is requirement for the 3rd liquid, regarding its solubility in the first two? As it is hard to find three liquids mutually not miscible.

Cyclohexyl chloride weighs in at 1 g/mL and"low" solubility in water according to Wikipedia. A small amounnt ofbromocyclohexane at 1.324 g/mL should allow you to "tune" the density of the organic layer.

The mixture water plus any oil and mercury will make a system of three immiscible liquids. Of course the densities of these liquids are not in the required domain.

According to this table, (methyl-)naphtalene or methylanthracene (or derivatives thereof) should be in the correct density range and not be soluble in water. It varies a bit depending on the subtitution.
https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hydrocarbon-boiling-melting-flash-autoignition-point-density-gravity-molweight-d_1966.html
